# Does Active Directory or Azure Active Directory have a backup of user accounts I can revert to?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, user-accounts, revert

Our organization uses a service called UMRA that automates Active Directory account creation, modification, deletion, and so on based on an education system. So if a new student is enrolled in said education system, UMRA automation kicks in and creates all their necessary accounts (Email, Active Directory, Google).

Our naming convention for our student accounts is

```
graduation year+first letter of first name+first letter of middle name+last name@stu.schooldistrict.org 
(e.g. 22jsmith@stu.schooldistrict.org).
```

On 07/01/2022 00:01 to 07/01/2022 11:01, our service UMRA modified 13,491 student accounts in our Active Directory by increasing the graduation year at the beginning of their AD accounts by 1

```
(e.g. 22jsmith@stu.schooldistrict.org to 23jsmith@stu.schooldistrict.org).
```

We are working with our UMRA rep right now to see what went wrong with the scripting automation and have disabled it for now, but my main problem right now (as a VERY new Sys Admin) is to revert those accounts back to their original graduation year.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Both AADS and Azure AD hare capable of recovering deleted objects but not rolling over latest changes. For that you will need previously created backups which AADS supports natively and Azure AD trough 3rd party solutions.